# Proving that a certain set is convex

Tags: elementary-set-theory, convex-analysis

I'm trying to prove that the set $W = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 2x_{1}^{2} + 3x_{2}^{2} \leq 4\}$ is convex. I've been trying to do this using the definition of W being convex when for all $x, y \in W $ and every $\lambda \in [0,1] $ we have $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in W $.

What I've done (I use $a$ in place of $\lambda$) thus far is rewrite $$2(ax_{1}+(1-a)y_{1})^{2}+3(ax_{2}+(1-a)y_{2})^{2}$$ to $$a^{2}(2x_{1}^{2}+3x_{2}^{2})+(1-a)^{2}(2y_{1}^{2}+3y_{2}^{2})+2a(1-a)(2x_{1}y_{1}+3x_{2}y_{2})$$

The part which I'm having trouble with is showing that $$2a(1-a)(2x_{1}y_{1}+3x_{2}y_{2}) \leq 2a(1-a)4 $$ or simply showing that

$$2x_{1}y_{1}+3x_{2}y_{2} \leq 4$$

How should I show that this is the case? Or if this is not necessary - how is it obvious that this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$u=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\sqrt2\\x_2\sqrt3\end{bmatrix}\qquad\text{and}\qquad v=\begin{bmatrix}y_1\sqrt2\\y_2\sqrt3\end{bmatrix}.$$

[Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) tells us that $$|u\cdot v|\le\sqrt{(u\cdot u)(v\cdot v)}\\|2x_1y_1+3x_2y_2|\le\sqrt{(2x_1^2+3x_2^2)(2y_1^2+3y_2^2)}.$$ Can you take it from there?

---

If you aren't familiar with Cauchy-Schwarz, then you can proceed in this way:

If $u=0,$ then the claim is easily shown, so suppose not. Note then that $$u\cdot\left(v-\frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}u\right)=u\cdot v-\frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}(u\cdot u)=u\cdot v-u\cdot v=0.$$ Hence, we have by dot-product properties that $$\begin{align}v\cdot v &= \left(v-\frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}u+\frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}u\right)\cdot\left(v-\frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}u+\frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}u\right)\\ &= \left(v-\frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}u\right)\cdot\left(v-\frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}u\right)-2\frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}u\cdot\left(v-\frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}u\right)+\left(\frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}u\right)\cdot\left(\frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}u\right)\\ &= \left(v-\frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}u\right)\cdot\left(v-\frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}u\right)+\frac{(u\cdot v)^2}{(u\cdot u)^2}(u\cdot u)\\ &= \left(v-\frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}u\right)\cdot\left(v-\frac{u\cdot v}{u\cdot u}u\right)+\frac{(u\cdot v)^2}{u\cdot u}\\ &\geq \frac{(u\cdot v)^2}{u\cdot u},\end{align}$$ so $$(u\cdot u)(v\cdot v)\geq(u\cdot v)^2,$$ and so $$|u\cdot v|=\sqrt{(u\cdot v)^2}\le\sqrt{(u\cdot u)(v\cdot v)}.$$

Comment: I get stuck at the same thing as before, but then with 4 replaced by $\max\{2x_1^2+3x_2^2,2y_1^2+3y_2^2\}$. I don't understand how I can show that $2x_{1}y_{1}+3x_{2}y_{2} \le\max\{2x_1^2+3x_2^2,2y_1^2+3y_2^2\}$.

Comment: I have given you what should be a better hint.

Answer (score 0):

Your set is of the form $\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{\frac{4}{3}} \leq 1$, after dividing by $4$.  This is the standard form for the equation of an ellipse.  Yes it is convex, yes it is obvious, and yes it is a good exercise to show it is convex in the way you're trying to.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_1,x_2)  ,  (y_1,y_2)\in W$ then we have
$$2x_1^2 +3x_2^2 \leq 4 ~~,2y_1^2+3y_2^2 \leq 4 $$
then we will have $$2(\lambda x_1)^2+3(\lambda x_2)^2\leq4\lambda^2\leq 4\lambda$$
and
$$2((1-\lambda )y_1)^2+3((1-\lambda) y_2)^2\leq4(1-\lambda)^2\leq 4(1-\lambda)$$

then $\lambda (x_1,x_2)+(1-\lambda)(y_1,y_2)\in W$ So $W$ is convex.